# Trying to implement a simple bubble sort function on a list of self declared arrays

Tags: c, function, bubble-sort, cs50

Newbie trying to make an arrays then sort them using a function called "sort" that i created at the bottom of the code, using bubble sort..

I'm pretty sure the printing part is ok, just the functions that I'm having trouble with, can someone help a newbie out please?..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void sort(int arrayRack[], int NumberOfArrayElements);

int main(void)

{
//variable declarations
int NumberOfArrayElements = 0;


//Get number of arrays
printf("number of arrays you'd like?\n");
NumberOfArrayElements = GetInt();

//variable array declaration
int arrayRack[NumberOfArrayElements];


//Get number for each int
for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfArrayElements; i++)
    {
        printf("give me an int for the %i th array\n", i + 1);
        arrayRack[i] = GetInt();
    }

//print what is currently in the arrayRack
for(int j = 0; j < NumberOfArrayElements; j++)
    printf("{%i}<-- number in %i-th array (unsorted)\n", arrayRack[j], j + 1);



for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfArrayElements; i++)
    {
        sort(&arrayRack[i], NumberOfArrayElements);
        printf("{%i}<-- number in %i-th array (sorted)\n", arrayRack[i], i + 1);

    }
    return 0;
}


//this is the funciton, like sort(haystack, size);
void sort(int arrayRack[], int NumberOfArrayElements)
{
//declare variable
int swap = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < NumberOfArrayElements; k++)
        {
            //if [1] is higher, swap with [2]
            if(arrayRack[k] > arrayRack[k + 1])
            {
                swap = arrayRack[k];
                arrayRack[k] = arrayRack[k + 1];
                arrayRack[k + 1] = swap;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a pointer to element `&arrayRack[i]` but in the parameters of sort you have declared the first parameter to be an array so this doesn't match. You could simply write:

In main:

```
sort(arrayRack, NumberOfArrayElements);
for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfArrayElements; i++)
    {
        printf("{%i}<-- number in %i-th array (sorted)\n", arrayRack[i], i + 1);

    }
```

And in sort function:

```
void sort(int arrayRack[], int NumberOfArrayElements)
{
//declare variable
int swap = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < NumberOfArrayElements-1; k++)
        {

           for(int j=0; j<NumberOfArrayElements-1-k;j++)

            if(arrayRack[j] > arrayRack[j + 1])
            {
                swap = arrayRack[j];
                arrayRack[j] = arrayRack[j + 1];
                arrayRack[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }

}
```

Also I would suggest `scanf("%d",&NumberOfArrayElements);` instead of `NumberOfArrayElements = GetInt();` and `scanf("%d",&arrayRack[i]);` instead of `arrayRack[i] = GetInt();`

Example:

```
 number of arrays you'd like?
    5
    give me an int for the 1 th array
    5 
    give me an int for the 2 th array
    7
    give me an int for the 3 th array
    1
    give me an int for the 4 th array
    8
    give me an int for the 5 th array
    3
    {5}<-- number in 1-th array (unsorted)
    {7}<-- number in 2-th array (unsorted)
    {1}<-- number in 3-th array (unsorted)
    {8}<-- number in 4-th array (unsorted)
    {3}<-- number in 5-th array (unsorted)
    {1}<-- number in 1-th array (sorted)
    {3}<-- number in 2-th array (sorted)
    {5}<-- number in 3-th array (sorted)
    {7}<-- number in 4-th array (sorted)
    {8}<-- number in 5-th array (sorted)
```

Comment: hmm.. Can you help me understand why we need two for loops instead of one, under the sort function please?

Comment: This is all about bubblesort implementation, bubblesort needs two loops and (that's why it has complexity O(n^2) ) , the basic idea behind the 2 loops it that we need to compare the with all the other elements, so element1 will be compared with all n-1 elements, element 2 will all n-2 elements (already compared with element 1 from previous step) element n will be compared with 0 elements (it is what has left) so total compare steps: n-1 + n-2 + ...+1+0 =O(n^2) (2 loops).

Comment: You could check the bubble sort algorithm here: http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/